# Problem with re.findall (duplicates)

Tags: python, html, regex

I tried to fetch source of 4chan site, and get links to threads.

I have problem with regexp (isn't working). Source:

```
import urllib2, re

req = urllib2.Request('http://boards.4chan.org/wg/')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = resp.read()

print re.findall("res/[0-9]+", html)
#print re.findall("^res/[0-9]+$", html)
```

The problem is that:

```
print re.findall("res/[0-9]+", html)
```

is giving duplicates.

I can't use:

```
print re.findall("^res/[0-9]+$", html)
```

I have read python docs but they didn't help.

Comment: And that is why 'parsing' HTML with regex never works. Get BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Which would return the exact same "duplicates". :)

Answer (score 11):

That's because there are multiple copies of the link in the source.

You can easily make them unique by putting them in a set.

```
>>> print set(re.findall("res/[0-9]+", html))
set(['res/3833795', 'res/3837945', 'res/3835377', 'res/3837941', 'res/3837942',
'res/3837950', 'res/3100203', 'res/3836997', 'res/3837643', 'res/3835174'])
```

But if you are going to do anything more complex than this, I'd recommend you use a library that can parse HTML. Either [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) or [lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml).